# why do I see server request like HEAD /https:/host.azurewebsites.net/

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have created an app service with app insight, I have not triggered any `get` or `post` event with the URL but I can see some exception in my app insight.
The URL is something strange like this HEAD /https:/appname.azurewebsites.net/

If the URL is wrong, it should not hit my app service and log anything in the App Insights. But how can I see log something like this.

and the exception is
`System.Web.HttpException: at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)`

Comment: If the exception only appears when you deploy your web app? And, if this exception could reproduce in local test? Or some scheduled tasks trigger some http request? It seems not to be a general problem.

Comment: I could see this in my another environment as well, I don't have any scheduled task, hope this is reproducible. Locally it is not a problem. I can see this in my azure portal only

Comment: Thanks for replying. And how often does this exception happen? I assume that it isn't related to any line of code.

Comment: Yes this is not related to any like of code. This happened twice initially, after nothing.
but how a request of this kind `/https:/appname.azurewebsites.net/` can even execute and hit any app service or the insight? Browser itself restrict such request. Correct me if I'm wrong!!

Comment: One possibility is app service health check, according to the doc, you may check if the http head request is `sent with User-Agent header set with value: Edge Health Probe`  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-health-probes

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is app service health check, according to the doc, you may check if the http head request is sent with User-Agent header set with value: Edge Health Probe

See:　https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-health-probes